# How to hide mouse over multiple frames?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I'm an actionscript n00b, please excuse my ignorance.
currently trying to make my first person shooter game and have picked up great tips from Lynda(.com) but im having difficulty changing my mouse into a crosshair cursor and having that crosshair not show up permanently in subsequent frames as I create this game.

so i have this code on an action layer but on other layers when I create another key frame to change what I shoot at on other layers, my cursor stamps a permanent image of itself onto the screen.  I definitely need to understand this language more if Im going to become good at it but for now i'f like to be able to make a few games to entertain myself, any suggestions? are appreciated

```
var cursor:MovieClip;

function initializeGame():void
{
cursor = new Cursor();
addChild(cursor);
cursor.enabled = false;
Mouse.hide();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
}

function dragCursor(event:MouseEvent):void
{
cursor.x = this.mouseX;
cursor.y = this.mouseY;
}

initializeGame();
```

Answer (score 0):

In AS3, items will remain on the display list (on screen) until explicitly removed (or their parent is removed).

So to keep your cursor from staying on screen, you need to remove it:

```
removeChild(cursor);
```

Doing `Mouse.show()` doesn't affect any display objects on the screen.

If you assign a new value to the var `cursor`, it doesn't automatically remove the previous object - as variables are just references to objects.  So if in your subsequent frames you are making a new cursor, you want to remove the existing one prior to assigning a new one to the variable:

```
if(cursor.parent)  removeChild(cursor); //if there is an object assigned to cursor, and it has a parent (which means it's on screen), then remove it before doing the below code
cursor = new Cursor();
addChild(cursor);
```